# Flutter test: The value of a foundation debug variable was changed by the test

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, testing, integration-testing

When I run my integration test, the test failed with this error:

```
[+1358 ms] flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[        ] flutter: The following assertion was thrown running a test:
[        ] flutter: The value of a foundation debug variable was changed by the test.
[        ] flutter: 
[        ] flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[        ] flutter: #0      debugAssertAllFoundationVarsUnset.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart:30:7)
[        ] flutter: #1      debugAssertAllFoundationVarsUnset (package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart:32:4)
[        ] flutter: #2      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._verifyInvariants (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:834:12)
[        ] flutter: #3      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:821:7)
[        ] flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] flutter: 
[        ] flutter: The test description was:
```

When I debug into the exception, I found that this checkpoint is failed:

```
debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride != null  // it is TargetPlatform.macos
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this error. The value can be changed everywhere and it make my test fail.
Any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same, my solution was:

You have to set the TargetPlatform to null before finishing of tests

```
 debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;

//  HERE RUN YOUR TESTS AND CHECKS

debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
```